# What is the usage of HDFS configuration in Java?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am little confused about HDFS Java API, especially the role of hadoop [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) against the config we put on hadoop server installation (*/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml*, etc).

1. Should I install the hadoop in every java client program that utilizes the hdfs?
2. Does any configuration set from java client affect how it communicates with hadoop server (hdfs server)?

Comment: which hadoop version are you using?

Comment: @ravindra I am using version 2.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set values for your parameters either in core-site.xml or through configuration in your driver code. The one set in the program will overwrite the one set in the xml file. So for example if you have to set a compression code. Then either you could add these to core-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value>
</property>
```

or add this line to your driver code.

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true");
 conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
```

And you dont need to install hadoop on every machine/node. Just install it in your master node and add datanodes by adding IP to the list. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_multi_node_cluster.htm) would help you in understanding how a multi node cluster has to be set up.

Comment: I looked at what values I can set through Configuration [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml), the `file.replication` also can be set. This is where I got confused, isn't that `file.replication` only be configured in hdfs server? I don't know exactly what config I can set in client and what can override the server configuration.

Comment: The one which you saw in the link is the default values for core-site.xml. Replication factor is something pertaining to a file or a cluster so if we want to set it in a cluster then add that to core-site.xml else pass that as a parameter in command line which placing that in HDFS. That is something which we dont need for configuration class at a program level.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. In every java client you should only import the hdfs Java package.
2. Example:

   ```
   public class HdfsTest {
       //download file from hdfs
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Configuration conf = new Configuration();
           conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://yourHadoopIP:9000/");
           conf.set("dfs.blocksize", "64");

           //to get a client of the hdfs system
           FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
           fs.copyToLocalFile(new Path("hdfs://yourHadoopIP:9000/jdk-7u65-linux-i586.tar.gz"), new Path("/root/jdk.tgz"));
           fs.close(); 
       }
   }
   ```